# How do I duplicate in knitr the output from the R console?

Tags: r, knitr, significant-digits

If I write in the R *console*

```
> 1.000000000000000123456 - 1
```

I get:

```
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

If I type this in an .Rnw file, *knitr* gives the following output in the PDF:

```
1 - 1
```

with result

```
0
```

How do I get knitr to reproduce the console in a particular block of code (preferably with the output not in scientific notation)?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question, but have you tried `\`r 1.000000000000000123456 - 1\``?

Comment: this works for me in a .Rmd file: `     ```{r echo=TRUE}
    1.000000000000000123456 - 1
    ``` `

Comment: My code in the .Rnw file is ```<<underflow>>=
1.000000000000000123456 - 1
@
``` Which corresponds to what @Maël and @Julian suggested